# How do I boot or install Ubuntu on a Windows 10 Tablet?

Tags: windows, tablet

I want to install Ubuntu on a Windows 10 PC Tablet, but my tablet isn't a Surface. It's a tablet from Sunstech. When I try to boot ubuntu from a usb, it displays a message, saying it can't recognise that usb.

Comment: Don't waste your time. Any Windows tablet from that brand runs on very Linux unfriendly CPUs. Installation is only for experts and not even those experts could come up with a solution for audio support.